# DDD can event handler construct value object for aggregate

Tags: event-handling, domain-driven-design, clean-architecture

Can I construct a value object in the event handler or should I pass the parameters to the aggregate to construct the value object itself? Seller is the aggregate and offer is the value object. Will it be better for the aggregate to pass the value object in the event?

```
    public async Task HandleAsync(OfferCreatedEvent domainEvent)
    {
        var seller = await this.sellerRepository.GetByIdAsync(domainEvent.SellerId);
        var offer = new Offer(domainEvent.BuyerId, domainEvent.ProductId, seller.Id);
        seller.AddOffer(offer);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

> should I pass the parameters to the aggregate to construct the value object itself?

You should probably default to passing the assembled value object to the domain entity / root entity.

The supporting argument is that we want to avoid polluting our *domain* logic with *plumbing* concerns.  Expressed another way, `new` is not a *domain* concept, so we'd like that expression to live "somewhere else".

Note: that by passing the value to the domain logic, you protect that logic from changes to the construction of the values; for instance, how much code has to change if you later discover that there should be a fourth constructor argument?

That said, I'd consider this to be a guideline - in cases where you discover that violating the guideline offers significant benefits, you should violate the guideline without guilt.

---

> Will it be better for the aggregate to pass the value object in the event?

Maybe?  Let's try a little bit of refactoring....

```
// WARNING: untested code ahead
public async Task HandleAsync(OfferCreatedEvent domainEvent)
{
    var seller = await this.sellerRepository.GetByIdAsync(domainEvent.SellerId);
    Handle(domainEvent, seller);
}

static Handle(OfferCreatedEvent domainEvent, Seller seller)
{
        var offer = new Offer(domainEvent.BuyerId, domainEvent.ProductId, seller.Id);
        seller.AddOffer(offer);
}
```

Note the shift - where `HandleAsync` needs to be aware of async/await constructs, `Handle` is just a single threaded procedure that manipulates two local memory references.  What that procedure does is copy information from the OfferCreatedEvent to the Seller entity.

The fact that `Handle` here can be static, and has no dependencies on the async shell, suggests that it could be moved to another place; another hint being that the implementation of `Handle` requires a dependency (`Offer`) that is absent from `HandleAsync`.

Now, within Handle, what we are "really" doing is copying information from OfferCreatedEvent to Seller.  We might reasonably choose:

```
seller.AddOffer(domainEvent);
seller.AddOffer(domainEvent.offer());
seller.AddOffer(new Offer(domainEvent));
seller.AddOffer(new Offer(domainEvent.BuyerId, domainEvent.ProductId, seller.Id));
seller.AddOffer(domainEvent.BuyerId, domainEvent.ProductId, seller.Id);
```

These are all "fine" in the sense that we can get the machine to do the right thing using any of them.  The tradeoffs are largely related to where we want to work with the information in detail, and where we prefer to work with the information as an abstraction.

In the common case, I would expect that we'd use abstractions for our domain logic (therefore: `Seller.AddOffer(Offer)`) and keep the details of how the information is copied "somewhere else".

The `OfferCreatedEvent -> Offer` function can sensibly live in a number of different places, depending on which parts of the design we think are most stable, how much generality we can justify, and so on.

Sometimes, you have to do a bit of war gaming: which design is going to be easiest to adapt if the most likely requirements change happens?

Comment: Will it be better for the aggregate to pass the value object in the event?

Answer (score 0):

I would also advocate for passing an already assembled value object to the aggregate in this situation. In addition to the reasons already mentioned by @VoiceOfUnreason, this also ***fits more naturally with the domain language***. Also, when reading code and method APIs you can then focus on domain concepts (like an offer) without being distracted by details until you really need to know them.

This becomes even more important if you would need to pass in more then one value object (or entity). Rather passing in all the values required for construction as parameters not only makes the API more resilient to refactoring but also burdens the reader with more details.

> The seller is receiving an offer.

Assuming this is what is meant here, fits better than something like the following:

> The seller receives some buyer id, product id, etc.

This most probably would not be found in conversations using the ***ubiquitous language***. In my opinion code should be as readable as possible and express the behaviour and business logic as close to human language as possible. Because you compile code for machines to execute it but the way you write it is for humans to easily understand it.

Note: I would even consider using *factory methods* on value objects in certain cases to unburden the client code of knowing what else might be needed to assemble a valid value object, for instance, if there are different valid constellations and ways of constructing the same value objects where some values need reasonable default values or values are chosen by the value object itself. In more complex situations a separate factory might even make sense.